# Как удалять системные сообщение в discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

как странно, но я не нашёл ничего что помогло бы мне.
нада просто удалять сообщения такие как `"БОТ закрепляет сообщение на этом канале."`

```
async def func():
    channel = client.get_channel(123XX)
    msg = await channel.send('**Завтрашнее расписание**')
    SYSTEM_MSG = await msg.pin()  # КАК УДАЛИТЬ ЭТО СООБЩЕНИЕ
```

ведь у `SYSTEM_MSG` нету метода `.delete()`

Answer (score 1):

Системные сообщения, такие как сообщения об закреплении, не могут быть удалены с помощью обычных методов. Однако вы можете использовать параметр `bulk` объекта TextChannel для удаления последних сообщений из канала, включая закрепленные сообщения.

Вот пример кода, который удаляет последние 100 сообщений из канала (включая закрепленные сообщения):

```
async def delete_system_messages(channel):
    # получаем последние 100 сообщений из канала
    messages = await channel.history(limit=100).flatten()
    
    # удаляем сообщения, которые не были написаны пользователями
    system_messages = [msg for msg in messages if msg.author == channel.guild.me]
    await channel.delete_messages(system_messages)
```

Вы можете вызвать эту функцию с объектом канала, чтобы удалить все системные сообщения из него:

```
channel = client.get_channel(123XX)
await delete_system_messages(channel)
```

Обратите внимание, что параметр bulk может использоваться только для удаления сообщений, написанных ботом. Попытка удалить сообщения, написанные другими пользователями, вызовет исключение `discord.Forbidden`.